# Ошибка в установке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

На моём компьютере у меня не получается установить Python поэтому я скачал на другой, и перенёс файлы на основной комп. Когда я запустил python мне вылезла ошибка :

```
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module Python runtime state: initialized Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python\lib\site.py", line 75, in <module>     import _sitebuiltins ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sitebuiltins'
```

Не знаю что делать.

Comment: может проще разобраться почему не получилось установить?

Comment: Снесите все останки и попробуйте заново. Если не получится, то объясните в вопросе пошагово, как вы устанавливаете

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin 
Я разбирался но ничего не получается. Хотел переустановить Python. Начал удалять через лаунчер , но пишет что нужно логнуться за админа чтобы удалять из этой папки, хотя я и так был за администратора. Удалил вручную. Но в лаунчере когда я хотел установить были только  3 кнопки - Uninstall, Modify , Repair. В первом не находит установленный python (Потому что я его удалил вручную) , а в последних двух просит администратора...

Comment: удаляли все папки по пути `C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37` ?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Да, когда я удалял всё вручную там была папка Python , и я сразу удалил папку Python.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Да, когда я удалял всё вручную там была папка Python , и я сразу удалил папку Python.

Comment: Лучше напишите логи/ошибку при устанвке.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874407/python-ipython-importerror-no-module-named-site/21874450

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/importerror-no-module-named-site-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

можно попробывать запустить инсталлер и нажать на кнопку Repair, потом когда действие закончить нажать на Uninstall

Answer (score -1):

нажми на значок поиска(рядом с пусокм) и напиши "py". удали все файлы с форматом .py и все файлы в которых есть надпись python

Comment: вандализмом попахивает от вашего ответа.

Comment: @Кирилл Неволин . Я уже это давно сделал